Getting input from edit text and saving it in a txt file in android studio
I am trying to write a database app where a dentist can add all the information of their patients. I am now designing the add new user part.
I am working with fragments so from my new fragment I want to get new patients information. I have added an action listener for the create button but it seems to fail at simple getText().toString().
Here is my code
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText name_field = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.patient_name);
                EditText phone_field = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.patient_phone);

                String new_name = name_field.getText().toString();
                String new_phone = phone_field.getText().toString();

                Log.d("heyyy", "done");


//                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
//                try {
//                    fileOutputStream = getActivity().openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
//
//                    fileOutputStream.write((name + " - " + phone + "\n").getBytes());
//
//                    fileOutputStream.close();
//                    Log.d("heyyy", "done");
//
//                }
//                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//                    Log.d("heyyy", "notfound output");
//                }
//                catch (IOException e) {
//                    Log.d("heyyy", "io output");
//                }


            }
        });
    }
}

The done is never printed.

I have tried to debug it so I know that line is the problem. When I click the button  the app just closes.

Does the code reach your click listener? When you debugged it, what was the values you saw? Is there a crash?
